# Error: defined function is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an application to add,save,read and delete notes in Node.js and my application is failing to read a function.

At first I didn't call the background code in my driver code, at that time I was getting a different error. Now that I've 'require' the file in my code it says "notes.addNotes is not a function"

```
const notes = require('./notes.js')
const yargs = require('yargs')

yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    description: 'Adds a new note',
    builder: {

        body: {

            description: 'Inside of the note',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string' 
        },
        title: {
            description: 'Note title',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'

        }

    },
    handler: function(argv){

    notes.addNotes(argv.title, argv.body)
    }
})
```

--------------------------------Notes.js file--------------------------------

```
const fs = require('fs')

const getNotes = function() {

}

const loadNotes = function() {

    try{

    const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
    const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString()
    return JSON.parse(dataJSON)

    } catch(error){

            return []

    }


}

const addNotes = function(title,body) {

    const notes = loadNotes()

    notes.push({
        title: title,
        body: body,
    })
    saveNotes(notes)
}

module.exports={
    getNotes: getNotes,
    addNote: addNotes
}
```

I expect a JSON file to be created when I add anything in the file, but the file is not being created and I'm getting an error saying notes.addNotes is not a function

Comment: just a typo exported as `addNote` calling as `notes.addNotes`

Comment: i.e. ... `addNote: addNotes` ... the exported property name has a missing `s` - use `module.exports={ getNotes, addNotes};` shorthand and this is less likely to happen :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you're setting "notes.addNote" to the addNotes function

```
module.exports={
    getNotes: getNotes,
    addNote: addNotes
}
```

Here you are calling "notes.addNotes" which does not exist in the scope.

```
notes.addNotes(argv.title, argv.body)
```

So either add or remove the 's' somewhere.